# Should we really be using html5 date input yet?

Tags: html

I've just been through Mark Pilgrim's post on html5 form widgets here:

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/forms.html

He implies that these elements should be adopted because they fallback to input=text. However on an (admittedly brief) test, it strikes me the behaviour of the date input, at least in safari, is actually inferior to a straight text input validated on the server.

Any views on this?

Comment: You're going to need to validate server side anyway, so in what way is the date input inferior to text input?

Comment: Exactly, client side validation, whether provided by HTML5 compatible browsers or by some sort of JavaScript library, is a convenience for users rather than a substitute for server side validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in your article, and the comments, there is no reason not to use this input type.

For browsers that do not support `type="date"`, the attribute will be ignored, and the field will render as `type="text"`, as that is the default.

You will want to validate that date server-side.  **Remember:**  Anyone can post anything to your scripts.

You can still validate the data client-side.  There are methods for detecting HTML5 form support here:  http://nicolahibbert.com/html5-forms-support-detection-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reason not to use `type="date"` (or at least to do so carefully): localized date formats.

If you use `<input type="date">` and the browser supports the `date` type, then you must specify the `value` attribute in ISO-8601 date format (like yyyy-MM-dd). If the browser *does not* support the `date` type, then you are going to want to show the date in the user's local date format (e.g. MM/dd/yyyy in the US).

On the server side, you could probably get sloppy and do something like this:

```
try
  parse date as ISO-8601
catch (Format Error)
  try
    parse date as local format
  catch (Format Error)
    show user error message
```

If you want to be as explicit as possible, you'll have to do some feature-detection on the client side, then enable `type="date"`, then change the date format of the `value` attribute, and maybe even manufacture a hidden form element that notifies the server that the date format coming from the form should be ISO-8601.